# Issue encrypting data using kernel crypto

Tags: c, linux, cryptography, kernel, aes

I'm trying to perform AES encryption using kernel crypto. I've pasted the code below. The code generates right output for ECB but not CBC. The only difference between both modes (code-wise) is IV data.

```
void do_aes_encrypt(Parameters *params)
{
        struct crypto_blkcipher *tfm = NULL;
        struct blkcipher_desc desc;
        struct scatterlist sgin, sgout;
        unsigned char *pin, *pout;
        int rv;

        pin = (unsigned char*) get_zeroed_page(GFP_KERNEL);
        pout = (unsigned char*) get_zeroed_page(GFP_KERNEL);
        memcpy(pin, params->input, params->dataLength);

        switch (params->mode) {
                case MODE_ECB:
                        tfm = crypto_alloc_blkcipher("ecb(aes)", 0, 0); break;
                case MODE_CBC:
                        tfm = crypto_alloc_blkcipher("cbc(aes)", 0, 0); break;
                default:
                        return;
        }

        desc.tfm = tfm;
        desc.flags = 0;

        if (crypto_blkcipher_setkey(tfm, params->key, params->keyLength)) {
                printk("Unable to set Key\n");
                goto free_return;
        }
        if (params->mode == MODE_CBC) {
                crypto_blkcipher_set_iv(tfm, params->iv, 16);
        }

        // Initialize the Scatterlists
        sg_init_one(&sgin, pin, params->dataLength);
        sg_init_one(&sgout, pout, params->dataLength);

        rv = crypto_blkcipher_encrypt(&desc, &sgout, &sgin, params->dataLength);
}
```

The kernel version I'm using is 4.15.18.

Update: Logs pasted below:

```
Mar  3 13:56:22 alg-kern kernel: [98671.587675] Mode   : CBC
Mar  3 13:56:22 alg-kern kernel: [98671.588511] Key    : [16]
Mar  3 13:56:22 alg-kern kernel: [98671.589263] INFO:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Mar  3 13:56:22 alg-kern kernel: [98671.590026] IV     : [16]
Mar  3 13:56:22 alg-kern kernel: [98671.590791] INFO:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Mar  3 13:56:22 alg-kern kernel: [98671.591613] Input  : [16]
Mar  3 13:56:22 alg-kern kernel: [98671.592480] INFO:  F3 44 81 EC 3C C6 27 BA   CD 5D C3 FB 08 F2 73 E6
Mar  3 13:56:22 alg-kern kernel: [98671.599025] DEBUG: Cleared switch statement
Mar  3 13:56:22 alg-kern kernel: [98671.599027] DEBUG: Cleared switch statement 2
Mar  3 13:56:22 alg-kern kernel: [98671.599925] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 000000000000000e
```

This is what I see in /var/log/syslog. 
My key, IV and input values are shown in the log above.

I've added some debug statements in the code and can confirm that the error is in "crypto_blkcipher_setkey" statement. The debug statement before this call is printed but not the one after that.

Code with debug statements for the above log (successfully prints "Cleared switch statement 2"):

```
LOG_DEBUG("Cleared switch statement");
if (!tfm) {
        printk("Unable to alocate cipher\n");
        return;
}
desc.tfm = tfm;
desc.flags = 0;

LOG_DEBUG("Cleared switch statement 2");

if (crypto_blkcipher_setkey(tfm, params->key, params->keyLength)) {
        printk("Unable to set Key\n");
        goto free_return;
}
LOG_DEBUG("Cleared crypto_blkcipher_setkey");
```

Comment: How do you determine that the code is correct or not?

Comment: Because for ECB I get the correct results.

Comment: Describe why the CBC result is not correct in your opinion. I did not ask why the ECB result is correct.

Comment: When I'm running CBC, the test dies, does not even generate an output.

Comment: RIP test I suppose. Describe how and where it "dies". Or does it simply run without error, but fail to fill `pout`?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I've updated the question with some logs.